# Integration estimate:$\frac{1}{r^\lambda} \int_{B_r(x)} \! |y|^{\lambda - n} \, dy < \infty $

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, analysis

I want to show that for $0< \lambda < n$ and $c_1>0$ fixed, we have

$$\frac{1}{r^\lambda} \int_{B_r(x)} \! |y|^{\lambda - n} \, dy \leq c < \infty $$

for any $x \in B_r(0) \subseteq\mathbb{R}^n, 0<r<c_1$. It is

$$\frac{1}{r^\lambda} \int_{B_r(x)} \! |y|^{\lambda - n} \, dy \leq \int_{B_r(x)} \! |y|^{- n} dy \leq \int_{B_r(0)} \! |y|^{- n} dy \leq \int_{B_{c_1}(0)} \! |y|^{- n}$$

so the assertion would be true if $\frac{1}{|y|^n} \in L^1(B_r(0))$, but i think this is not true? I'm thankful for any suggestions on how to continue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, Using polar coordinate for every $x\in\Bbb R $ we get 
$$\frac{1}{r^\lambda} \int_{B_r(x)} \! |y-x|^{\lambda - n} \, dy= |\Bbb S^{n-1}|\frac{1}{r^\lambda}\int_{0}^r \! |\rho|^{\lambda - n} \rho^{n-1}\, d\rho \\=|\Bbb S^{n-1}|\frac{1}{r^\lambda}\int_{0}^r \! \rho^{\lambda - 1}  \, d\rho  = \frac{|\Bbb S^{n-1}|}{\lambda}\tag{I}$$

1. **If $0<\lambda< n$ then from (I) we have,**

$$\frac{1}{r^\lambda} \int_{B_r(x)} \! |y|^{\lambda - n} \, dy=\frac{1}{r^\lambda} \int_{B_r(x)\cap B_r(0)} \! |y|^{\lambda - n} \, dy+\frac{1}{r^\lambda} \int_{B_r(x)\cap B^c_r(0)} \! |y|^{\lambda - n} \, dy\\\le\frac{1}{r^\lambda} \int_{ B_r(0)} \! |y|^{\lambda - n} \, dy+\frac{1}{r^\lambda} \int_{B_r(x)\cap B^c_r(0)} \! |y|^{\lambda - n} \, dy \\=\frac{|\Bbb S^{n-1}|}{\lambda} +\frac{1}{r^\lambda} \int_{B_r(x)\cap B^c_r(0)} \! |y|^{\lambda - n} \, dy $$

However, Since $x\in B_r(x)$ we have,  $y\in B_r(x)\cap B^c_r(0) \implies r\le |y|\le |x|+|y-x|\le  2r \implies (2r)^{\lambda-n} \le |y|^{\lambda-n}\le r^{\lambda-n}$

Accordingly,

$$\frac{1}{r^\lambda} \int_{B_r(x)\cap B^c_r(0)} \! |y|^{\lambda - n} \, dy \le \frac{1}{r^\lambda} \int_{B_r(x)} \! r^{\lambda - n} \, dy \le r^{-n}|B_r(x)| = |B_1(0)| $$

That is, $$\color{blue}{\frac{1}{r^\lambda} \int_{B_r(x)} \! |y|^{\lambda - n} \, dy\le  |B_1(0)|+ \frac{|\Bbb S^{n-1}|}{\lambda}}$$

3. **Now If $\lambda> n$** **then we proceed as follows.**

Since,  $x\in B_r(0)$ i.e $|x|\le r$ we have,

$$\frac{1}{r^\lambda} \int_{B_r(x)} \! |x|^{\lambda - n} \, dy\le r^{-n}|B_r(x)| = |B_1(0)|\tag{II} $$

- On other hand,  $|y| \le|x|+|y-x| $. And since $\lambda >n$ we have, $$\color{red}{|y|^{\lambda - n}\le (|x|+|y-x|)^{\lambda - n}\le 2^{\lambda -n}(|x|^{\lambda - n}+|y-x|^{\lambda - n})}\tag{III}$$

Therefore,  from I, II, III we have,

$$\frac{1}{r^\lambda} \int_{B_r(x)} \! |y|^{\lambda - n} \, dy\le \frac{ 2^{\lambda -n}}{r^\lambda} \int_{B_r(x)} \! |x|^{\lambda - n} \, dy+\frac{ 2^{\lambda -n}}{r^\lambda} \int_{B_r(x)} \! |y-x|^{\lambda - n} \, dy\\\le 2^{\lambda -n}( |B_1(0)|+ \frac{|\Bbb S^{n-1}|}{\lambda})$$

That is, $$\color{blue}{\frac{1}{r^\lambda} \int_{B_r(x)} \! |y|^{\lambda - n} \, dy\le 2^{\lambda -n}( |B_1(0)|+ \frac{|\Bbb S^{n-1}|}{\lambda})}$$

Comment: Thank you very much for the detailed answer! Most of it is clear now, the only thing i don't understand ist (III). Since $\lambda - n$ < 0, wouldn't it be $|y|^{\lambda - n} \geq (|x| + |y - x|)^{\lambda - n}$ or do i miss something here?

Comment: you are right. But that case is more easier.

Comment: I'm not sure if i understand it right, but in this case it is enough to consider (I)? We have $\int_{B_r(x)} \! |y|^{\lambda - n} dy \leq \int_{B_r(0)} \! |y|^{\lambda - n} dy$ for any $x$, so if we use (I) with $x=0$ we should already have the needed bound.

Comment: Great post, thank you very much again, it was very helpful.

Comment: you are welcome sweeetie

Comment: Sorry, i have to ask one more thing: where does the second estimate in (III) come from? I think it uses Young's inequality and maybe an general version of the binomial theorem, but i can't exactly figure out how to do it

Comment: Use the convexity of $x^p$

Comment: Alright, thanks again!